# Expression for comparing attribute value in camel Java DSL

Tags: java, xpath, apache-camel

I'd like to write an expression with XPath for comparing an attribute value in my xml message header with a certain value to direct it to an appropriate folder. The XML header is

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cda\render\cda.xsl"?>
    <Books xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"
        xmlns:classCode="DOCCLIN" xmlns:moodCode="EVN"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 ./cda_r2_normativewebedition2010/infrastructure/cda/CDA.xsd">
        <realmCode code="DE" />
        <typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" extension="POCD_HD000040" />
        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.29" />
        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.33" />
        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.33.1.1" />
        <id extension="2015121415313522" />
        <code code="12.3.34.65" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"
            codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Document" />
        <title>Prices</title>
        <effectiveTime value="201512141531+0000" />
        <confidentialityCode code="N" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.25" />
        <languageCode code="de-DE" />
```

I would like to compare a certain node attirbute (Attribute code of the code Element) to a value and direct it to a folder it that holds true.

I wrote something like

```
from("file:testxml/")
                .choice()
                .when()
//              .xpath("urn:hl7-org:v3:Books/urn:hl7-org:v3:code/@code = '12.3.34.65'")
                .xpath("urn:hl7-org:v3:ClinicalDocument/urn:hl7-org:v3:code[@code='12.3.34.65']")
                .to("file:xPath/")
                .to("direct:xpath");

            }
```

I want to check whether the value of the attribute is '12.3.34.65'. Could you please correct me and let me know to how to write the xpath expression in the right manner.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You sample xml is not valid. Also the attribute code of code element is not '12.3.34.65'. Try below to redirect output to destinationFolder.

```
from("file:testxml")
 .choice()
  .when()
   .xpath("/Books/code[@code='x.x.x.x']")
   .to("file:destinationFolder");
```

Comment: You are right about the attribute value, but I had mistakenly pasted the abstract value. I have corrected it now. I tested the XML using the value '12.3.34.65'. The code you wrote is the same as the I wrote but without the namespace. Without the namespace reference, the expression wouldn't work.